# How to display total of MySQL column in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am just having a bit of trouble, not super experienced with MySQL. Here's my code:

```
    // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id, client, package, rate, term_start, term_end, last_billed FROM clients";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


    echo "<table><tr><th>Client</th><th>Package</th><th>Rate</th><th>Term Start</th><th>Term End</th><th>Last Billed</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["client"] . "</td><td>" . $row["package"]. "</td><td>$" . $row["rate"]. "</td><td>" . date("M\(m\) j, Y", strtotime($row["term_start"])) . "</td><td>" . date("M\(m\) j, Y", strtotime($row["term_end"])) . "</td><td>" . date("M\(m\) j, Y g:i a", strtotime($row["last_billed"])) . "</td><td><div class='tags'><a href=''>Details</a><a href=''>Send Invoice</a></div></td></tr>";
    }

    echo "<tr><td></td><td></td><td>" . $row["rate_sum"] . "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";

$conn->close();
```

As you can see I want the sum of all things in column row to total out. I know it's `SELECT SUM(rate) AS rate_sum FROM clients` to get it to return at "rate_sum" but how do I make the SQL call while making the other one at the same time?

Comment: @IdontDownVote I can do what I want with "SELECT SUM(rate) AS rate_sum FROM clients" but how do I call it using PHP to display?

Comment: they deleted their comment and posted an answer, that's why they're not responding to you in comments. So, nice answer huh? Looks like a winner to me; *what say ye?*

Comment: @Tony Why did you delete your new question? Did you resolve it?

Comment: @mickmackusa - I did, after reading the comments I went to review and the gentleman was correct, it was a typo. Very embarrassing. Thank you so much for you assistance though!

Answer (score 3):

this can be done in the query like so.

```
SELECT id, client, package, rate, SUM(rate) as total, term_start, term_end, last_billed 
FROM clients
group by id with Rollup
```

the last row will have an id of null and the total you want.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-modifiers.html

This is not be the most common use of ROLLUP, its more often used as an super aggrigate when you are already doing an aggrigate, say group sales by month and get the grand total. However if you need the data to come from the query rather than being calculated outside, grouping on id will make it just like a simple sum. It does have downsides regarding sorting and limit.

Comment: This is a pretty interesting solution, I'd never heard of Rollup before.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I've never heard of `WITH ROLLUP` before either (certainly worth an up 1).  phpMyAdmin doesn't like it when I type it into the SQL textbox, but it runs the query just fine (claims that it doesnt' recognize `WITH ROLLUP`.  I decided to educate myself with this technique and post a fully implemented and tested solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add up the values during your loop, like this;

```
echo "<table><tr><th>Client</th><th>Package</th><th>Rate</th><th>Term Start</th><th>Term End</th><th>Last Billed</th></tr>";  

//declare the variable `$rate_sum` to start at 0
$rate_sum = 0;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $row["client"] . "</td><td>" . $row["package"] . "</td><td>$" . $row["rate"] . "</td><td>" . date("M\(m\) j, Y", strtotime($row["term_start"])) . "</td><td>" . date("M\(m\) j, Y", strtotime($row["term_end"])) . "</td><td>" . date("M\(m\) j, Y g:i a", strtotime($row["last_billed"])) . "</td><td><div class='tags'><a href=''>Details</a><a href=''>Send Invoice</a></div></td></tr>";

    //for every row, add the rate to the `$rate_sum` variable
    $rate_sum += $row['rate'];
}

echo "<tr><td></td><td></td><td>" . $rate_sum . "</td></tr>";
```

---

### Side Note

I'd also like to note that, while you are technically writing your code *correctly*, there are some general guidelines you should probably try to get in the habit of doing because it will help you tremendously.

The main one, code indentation. Your current code is a bit hard to read, because you have lines of code that are extremely long for no real reason.

Another thing is, you should not be using `echo` to output HTML in *most* cases (There are some cases, such as very small elements where this would be fine, but for anything that is multi-line, you should switch out of PHP to display your HTML, and use PHP for only variables.)

Here is an example of how you could have written your code that makes it **easier to read**, **gives you proper syntax highlighting**, and **is easier to understand in general**. (This is using [PHP Alternative Syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) (Thanks Jeto!))

Make sure to include `$rate_sum = 0;` in your PHP.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Client</th>
        <th>Package</th>
        <th>Rate</th>
        <th>Term Start</th>
        <th>Term End</th>
        <th>Last Billed</th>
    </tr>
    <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $row['client'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['package'] ?></td>
            <td><?= $row['rate'] ?></td>
            <td><?= date('M\(m\) j, Y', strtotime($row['term_start'])) ?></td>
            <td><?= date('M\(m\) j, Y', strtotime($row['term_end'])) ?></td>
            <td><?= date('M\(m\) j, Y g:i a', strtotime($row['last_billed'])) ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php $rate_sum += $row['rate']; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><?=$rate_sum;?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Nice answer. Oh, "my 2 cents" here. Your 2nd code block for the `<tr><td>`'s, can be backed up a tad and line up with the other 2 ;-) edit: Oh, and I won't have to scroll over to the right to see the rest :p

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner In my code I've always used the PHP beginning and ending tags as their own element respectively, that's why I tabbed the loop block out an extra time, is this not standard practice?

Comment: Since this page is a Code Review, I'll add my 2 cents too.  I see lots of early programmers getting caught out with typo issues while bouncing in and out of php to display their data -- for this reason I don't bang on too hard about multiple `echo`s.  The last table row doesn't have enough columns in it.  Calling `date(strtotime())` is a bit cumbersome to look at while printing to screen; instead consider modifying the query to format the date column so that the result set is completely prepared.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for your comment. For my answer I really wanted to touch mostly on indentation/syntax, but I think your comment would be useful to OP.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton No no.... I was just talking about from a "graphic" point of view on how the 2nd block didn't line up. I'm a front-end coder also.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yeah, nowadays I'm much more used to using templating languages, which make everything line up way better. I think the code would look more messy if I tabbed back that `<tr>` block though, because the ending and beginning PHP tags would be on the same line.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Yeah, I noticed that also earlier, about if you did that the PHP tags wouldn't line up. Meh... no biggie right? ;-) :D *Cheers*. Ok... didn't mean to tie up comments here, but this is code related after all ;-)

Comment: Nice answer but while we're at it, I'd suggest using [PHP's alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for the template part (`while` block). Also removing `;` from `<?= $value; ?>` statements as they don't serve any purpose in this case (and are ugly :))

Comment: @Jeto Updated the answer. Thanks for the documentation for alternative syntax :)

Comment: gotta wonder why there hasn't been a few extra votes from mine (47 mins. ago) and a pal 'o mine too who isn't present here. C'mon guys, be generous here! hahaha!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also calculate in while loop as:

```
 $rate_sum =0;
    // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
         $rate_sum=$rate_sum+$row["rate"];
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row["client"] . "</td><td>" . $row["package"]. "</td><td>$" . $row["rate"]. "</td><td>" . date("M\(m\) j, Y", strtotime($row["term_start"])) . "</td><td>" . date("M\(m\) j, Y", strtotime($row["term_end"])) . "</td><td>" . date("M\(m\) j, Y g:i a", strtotime($row["last_billed"])) . "</td><td><div class='tags'><a href=''>Details</a><a href=''>Send Invoice</a></div></td></tr>";
        }

echo $rate_sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd present an alternative solution where all of the preparation is done in the query.  This avoids using a counter or performing any date formatting or prepending of `$` while presenting with php.  The only part that I am not crazy about is that MYSQL doesn't offer a date format character for lowercase `am` and `pm` -- so I have to use a couple more function calls. :(

Code:

```
$query = "SELECT id,
                 client,
                 package,
                 CONCAT('$', SUM(rate)),
                 DATE_FORMAT(term_start, '%b(%c) %e, %Y'),
                 DATE_FORMAT(term_end, '%b(%c) %e, %Y'),
                 CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(last_billed, '%b(%c) %e, %Y %l:%i') , LOWER(DATE_FORMAT(last_billed, ' %p')))
          FROM clients
          GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP";

if (!$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db")) {
    echo "Database Connection Error: " , $conn->connect_error;
} elseif (!$result = $conn->query($query)) {
    echo "Syntax Error: " , $conn->error; // never show actual error messaget to public
} elseif (!$result->num_rows) {
    echo "No Rows Found";
} else {
    $colheads = ["Client", "Package", "Rate", "Term Start", "Term End", "Last Billed"];
    echo "<table border=1><tr><th>" , implode("</th><th>", $colheads) , "</th></tr>";
        while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            if (array_shift($row) !== null) {
                echo "<tr><td>" , implode("</td><td>", $row) , "</td></tr>";
            } else {
                  // rate changed from [3] to [2] via array_shift()
                echo "<tr><td colspan=2></td><td>{$row[2]}</td><td colspan=3></td></tr>";
            }       
        }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

This is the result set from my fake db data:

[image]

I need to include `id` in the result set for the `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP` "magic" to work.  `id` is the column that signals the "total" row by offering a value of `null`. Also, notice that I have to remove the `id` element (first element) from the `$row` variable so that `implode()` works as desired.

Here is the output:

[image]